# How to get the sum of specific rows in datagrid

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I created a datagrid that i populated. how can i get the sum of specific rows that has thesame entry. For example, on my colum there are two types, CREDIT and DEBIT, I want to get all the sum of the debit rows and put it on a textbox named creditTotal.text and thesame for debit.

Comment: You have a column in called Type with the values of either CREDIT of DEBIT and another column with monetary a amounts? And you just want to total the rows where Type = Debit? With no code and no example of the table fields, it is hard to figure out what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a ADO.Net `DataTable` you could do

```
`Dim sum As Integer = 0

For Each dr As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(dr("Amount"))
Next`
```

Now u can add that the value of `sum` to the `TextBox` as `TextBox.Text= sum.ToString()`

Comment: What i want is to compute the sum of the debit column and also the credit column., on the credit total, the debit cells will not be included on the computation because it is not part of the condition,

Comment: The question is tagged vb.net. Pleas don't provide c# code.

Comment: A link to a video is not acceptable. Edit your answer to show the vb.net code.